# Can't get an Nvidia driver to work 12.04

Tags: nvidia

I've been tearing my hair out trying to get an Nvidia driver for my GTX650-Ti to install and work.

After a clean install of 12.04, installing the driver from "Additional Drivers" and installing with `apt-get install nvidia-current` both result in my install booting, but not being able to log in.

There is so much material on installing nvidia drivers, but nothing seems to work for me. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I went back to lubuntu 13.10, the distro I originally wanted (I was just trying LTS to see if it would be better).

No joy with `nvidia-current` so I added the [x-swat](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) ppa and installed `nvidia-331`. `nvidia-current` was installing `nvidia-304`.

Works now.

N.b. if anyone is using this information. Check with the nvidia website which driver you need for your card (331, 304, 319 or whatever), and install that one using apt. Dont forget to run `nvidia-xconfig` and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the suitable Nvidia driver from [here](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/304.51/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.51.run)
2. Install the driver manually [This link will help you](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-304.108-driver)
3. To install it manually

First press ctrl + alt +f1 This will open tty1

Now you are using the tty terminal console

log in with your user name and password

Now stop the lightdm(dgm or whatever) using the command

```
sudo stop lightdm
```

Then install the new driver with

```
sudo sh /path-to-the-driver
```

- if something goes wrong close the installer and reboot then try again
- still same problem the nvidia installer will make a black list in /etc/modprobe.d/
- if this is not generated you have to make such file to black list nouveau
- Run sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf and fill it with this:
  blacklist nouveau
- If the problem is not solve you have to add the string "nomodeset" to your /etc/default/grub, in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= line
- then update the grub

  `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest updating nvidia driver to the latest version using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates-dev
```

Comment: Didn't work for my card